# Check if a column's integer is in another column's string of integers

Tags: python, pandas

A dataframe has two columns. One has a single integer per row. The other has a string of multiple integers, separated by ',', per row:

```
import pandas as pd
duck_ids = ["1, 4, 5, 7", "3, 11, 14, 27"]
ducks_of_interest = [4,15]
duck_df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "DucksOfInterests": ducks_of_interest,
        "DuckIDs": duck_ids
    }
)
print(f"The starting dataframe:\n{duck_df}")


   DucksOfInterests        DuckIDs
0                 4     1, 4, 5, 7
1                15  3, 11, 14, 27
```

A new column is required that returns a True if the Duck of Interest is within the set of Duck IDs. This is attempted using a simple lambda function with the .apply method:

```
duck_df['DoIinDIDs'] = duck_df.apply(lambda x: str(x['DuckIDs']) in [x['DucksOfInterests']], axis=1)
```

This was expected to return a True for the first row, as 4 is a number in "1, 4, 5, 7", and False for the second row. However, the result is False for both rows:

```
print(f"The dataframe with the additional column:\n{duck_df}")

   DucksOfInterests        DuckIDs  DoIinDIDs
0                 4     1, 4, 5, 7      False
1                15  3, 11, 14, 27      False
```

What is the error in the code or the approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were almost there but unnecessarily used a list and swapped the names:

```
duck_df['DoIinDIDs'] = duck_df.apply(lambda x: str(x['DucksOfInterests'])
                                     in x['DuckIDs'], axis=1)
```

Output:

```
   DucksOfInterests        DuckIDs  DoIinDIDs
0                 4     1, 4, 5, 7       True
1                15  3, 11, 14, 27      False
```

Note, however, that this approach might fail as you rely on the whole string and `4` would be found in `1, 14, 20`.

You can instead `split` the string:

```
duck_df['DoIinDIDs'] = duck_df.apply(lambda x: str(x['DucksOfInterests'])
                                     in x['DuckIDs'].split(', '), axis=1)
```

Finally, as `apply` on `axis=1` is slow, you can replace the whole thing by a list comprehension:

```
duck_df['DoIinDIDs'] = [str(a) in b.split(', ')
                        for a, b in zip(duck_df['DucksOfInterests'],
                                        duck_df['DuckIDs'])]
```

Comment: I hadn't realised the error you noted, thank you for pointing this out and explaining the use of split to avoid this issue.

Comment: You're welcome. Also, if you don't have a reliable separator you could use a regex instead (`str(a) in re.findall('\d+', b)`). Or even `bool(re.search(fr'\b{a}\b', b))` in place of `str(a) in b.split(', ')`

Answer (score 1):

You have two issues, you need to replace the order of `DucksOfInterests` and `DuckIDs` and you need to convert the string to list of ints rather than the int to string, `"4" in "3, 11, 14, 27"` will return `True`

```
duck_df['DoIinDIDs'] = duck_df.apply(lambda x: x['DucksOfInterests'] in map(int, x['DuckIDs'].split(',')), axis=1)
```